# ,Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: java, file-io

I am trying to write a code to remove comment line from the input java file. I am getting this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
```

It is showing error in `return new String(buffer)`, and the word "String" everywhere in the program.

```
package javaapplication3;  
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;

public class JavaApplication3 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String source = readFile("sorce.java");    
        System.out.println(source.replaceAll("(?:/\\*(?:[^*]|(?:\\*+[^*/]))*\\*+/)|    (?://.*)",""));    
    }

    static String readFile(String fileName) {    
        File file = new File(fileName);    
        char[] buffer = null;    
        try {    
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(
                new FileReader(file));    
            buffer = new char[(int)file.length()];    
            int i = 0;    
            int c = bufferedReader.read();
            while (c != -1) {
                buffer[i++] = (char)c;
                c = bufferedReader.read();    
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {    
            e.printStackTrace();  
        }  
        return new String(buffer);
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you getting an IOException? Because you are catching it and do nothing. So it is possible that you are trying to create a new String with a null char array.

Comment: You should print out the exception in your catch statement, you'll find some useful information.

Comment: If you don't find the file, you return `null`... `char[] buffer = null;` - I'd recommend a `StringBuilder` anyway.

Comment: String Builder.....!! Sir, Can you suggest me something about this...Because I dont know this.

Answer (score 0):

You initialized `buffer` to `null`, and it must still be `null` at

```
return new String(buffer);
```

Therefore, this line in the `try` block never ran:

```
buffer = new char[(int)file.length()];
```

There must have been an `IOException` thrown in the line above it, but you caught it and ignored it.  That is probably the worst thing you can do when catching an exception.

Properly handle the `IOException` by at least printing a stack trace.  Then you can fix the cause of that exception and get your code to work.

But if there is an `IOException`, then you must handle that case properly with regards to avoiding the `NullPointerException`, possibly by letting the caller of the method handle the `IOException`.

Comment: Thank you Sir for your valuable reply.I have added a -printing a stack trace in catch block

Comment: .....Its asking me to remove the statement which prints the stack trace in catch block!!!!

Answer (score 0):

You must never initialized a variable with "null" if you don't want that this variable was null.

Try, char buffer [ ]= new char[ ];

Advice:
put always in your method main:

public static void main(String[ ] args)throws IOException{